# How can I pull a list of all the envelopes sent/received by all the users (like in report tab) through Docusign REST API?

Tags: docusignapi

I am an admin account user and to get insights from data I need to pull the details of all the envelopes from all accounts. The similar thing is what a report provides in Docusign dashboard but I need the list of recipients as well. Can anyone please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Listing envelopes sent by your users: [Envelopes::listStatusChanges](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges)

I think that call may cover envelopes sent by anyone in your account (if the accessToken represents a user with admin privileges). But I'm not sure.

If it doesn't then you can loop through the account's users.

Tracking who has received an envelope through their DocuSign account is done with the [Folders::listItems](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Folders/Folders/listItems) API call. You may need to list both the Inbox and Deleted folders. You also need to check that the person signed the specific envelope vs receiving it for some other reason (cc, certified copy, etc).

Finally, an alternative if you have higher volumes is to purchase the DocuSign Report Feed product (see note below). It will send you DB table dumps about your account activity on a regular basis so you can do your own reporting on DocuSign activity. It is the best way to have full access to report data. Ask your DocuSign contact for more info.

Note: I'm not sure of the exact name for the reporting product.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if you install DocuSign for Salesforce managed package and use Connect feature in DocuSign. Configure your webhooks to create DocuSign Status and DocuSign Recipient Status records for each send. Any DocuSign objects or custom object can be used in the Connect configuration, after selecting objects, select which events you want the results to be pushed back to Salesforce.

Use a parent object to store envelope details and child object for the recipient data. Use `Envelope Id` to relate the child records to the parent. Eventually, you will be able to build various reports on Salesforce.

More info here: https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-admin-guide-ds-connect-for-salesforce